# EJB3 with Spring Java Configuration

Tags: spring, ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean

I need to inject a spring bean into an EJB 3 stateless session bean. The spring bean is declared in a jar file and initialized via a spring @Configuration class. All the examples I have run into thus far only suggest using beanRefContext.xml file (to maintain a single application context). But as all our spring beans are defined using java configuration, is there a way to combine the beanRefContext.xml file and spring's java configuration? 
In short, is there a way to use the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext as the bean factory from a beanRefContext?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

Here is the solution:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <value type="java.lang.Class">com.company.app.SpringConfiguration</value>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You have to use `<list>` because of how Spring handles varargs in constructor argument.